# Matrix representation of position operator in terms of Hamiltionian eigenfunctions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, matrix-elements

Consider the normalized eigenfunctions $\psi_1(x),\dots,\psi_N(x)$ of the hermitian Hamiltonian $H(x,p_x)$.

I want to find the matrix representation of $x$ in the basis of the eigenfunctions of $H$.

The matrix element $\textbf{x}_{mn}$ is given by $\langle \psi_m(x)|x|\psi_n(x)\rangle$. It seems like the given eigenfunctions are not related to $x$, so how can I determine these matrix elements?

Thanks.

Comment: $\hat{x} = x\hat{1}$ in position representation. So you just get $\int  \psi_m(x)^\star x \psi_n(x)dx =: x_{mn}$

Comment: Maybe to elaborate, you can show that $\langle \psi_m|\hat{x} |\psi_n \rangle = \langle \psi_m (x)|x \psi_n (x) \rangle$ using the resolution of the identity $\hat{1} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}|x \rangle \langle x| dx$ and the fact that the LHS of the first expression is in Dirac notation whereas the RHS is in position representation (LHS = left hand side)